# Formating dynamically added labels in JavaFX

Tags: java, loops, javafx, label, gridpane

I'm trying to change the background color of dynamically created labels. However, I can't seem to understand how to achieve this? Attached code snipped below. How can I change the background colors of the labels created and added to the GridPane?

```
private GridPane similarity_matrix;
 for (int j = 0; j < files.size(); j++) {
                //Print out the corresponding similarity scores
                similarity_matrix.add(new Label((two_point.format(matrix[i][j]))), i + 1, j + 1);
        }
```

Comment: Construct the `Label`, configure it, and when it is done, add it. If you want to change the color later, you'll have to keep reference to each label or retrieve them using `getColumnIndex` and `getRowIndex` methods.

Comment: [mcve] please ..  and please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.